# Is there a tool I can use to quickly check which versions of Python a library is compatible with?

Tags: python

When developing frontend applications, people often use https://caniuse.com/ to determine browser compatibility.

Is there anything similar for Python? For example, lets say I want to use `argparse`. I can enter it into the tool and it will tell me that only Python 3.0 and 3.1 don't have it available.

This is the error pycharm is giving me: [image]

Comment: You could look on pypi.org for packages, say Flask, and in the project details section it lists python versions.

Comment: Can the people downvoting at least say *why* they're downvoting? I don't see what's wrong with this question.

Comment: I believe that you haven't listed the problem that Pycharm gives you, so the question looks like the one with _recommend of find_.

Comment: Yes but initially this question had nothing to do with PyCharm and I was still being downvoted.

Comment: @Ogen related, but still no answer [pyCharm writes "python version 2.7 doesn't have module pathlib" while project interpreter is set to 3.5.2. (mac os high sierra)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000027564-pyCharm-writes-python-version-2-7-doesn-t-have-module-pathlib-while-project-interpreter-is-set-to-3-5-2-mac-os-high-sierra-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find such information on [pypi.org](http://pypi.org), but you can fully count only on well maintained packages, since they usually run all tests against python versions, that they list.

e.g. 
https://pypi.org/project/argparse/

> **Programming Language**
>       Python 
>       Python :: 2 
>       Python :: 2.3 
>       Python :: 2.4 
>       Python :: 2.5 
>       Python :: 2.6 
>       Python :: 2.7 
>       Python :: 3 
>       Python :: 3.0 
>       Python :: 3.1 
>       Python :: 3.2 
>       Python :: 3.3 
>       Python :: 3.4

Comment: Yeah it's weird because my PyCharm IDE is saying the `argparse` module is not available with Python 3.1 but the PyPi.org listing of `argparse` states that it *is* compatible with Python 3.1...

Comment: @Ogen i've never seen such warning/error in Pycharm, can you show what it's telling you?